# Error in String formating while insert in a RDS table

Tags: python, postgresql, google-drive-api, amazon-rds, psycopg2

as I try to insert a few data into a table, i get that error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

My code looks like that (just remove some sensitive parts)

```
for item in reversed(items):
    parents = item['parents']
    folder_id = item['id']
    created_time = item['createdTime']
    salvarDB(parents, folder_id, created_time)
```

and

```
import psycopg2
import logging

def salvarDB (parents, folder_id, created_time):
  #função para enviar dados para o RDS
  try:
    psconn = psycopg2.connect(host="", port = , database="", user="", password="")
    queryInsert ="""
            insert into public."Folders"
                            (
                              google_drive_id,
                              google_drive_path,
                              "createdTime",
                              parent,
                              permission_status
                              )
                              VALUES (%%s, %s, %s, %%s, %s)""" % folder_id, None, created_time, parents, "e182c2c8-46ea-472c-adab-c49d60a2998a")
    cursor = psconn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(queryInsert)
    psconn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    psconn.close()
  except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
```

I change that line:

```
VALUES (%%s, %s, %s, %%s, %s)""" % folder_id, None, created_time, parents, "e182c2c8-46ea-472c-adab-c49d60a2998a")
```

To:

```
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')''' % (folder_id, None, created_time, parents, "e182c2c8-46ea-472c-adab-c49d60a2998a")
```

and i got another error:

syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 10: ...', 'None', '2020-06-23 18:45:58.990000+00:00', '['0ADmCT94wu...

and last here a exeample of items content:

`{'parents': ['1bX__7p5rkhjFEmNtkfvQFPdbat'], 'id': '1lAixT6Z0qvyHxYa7DkCfSUxUiI', 'name': '220923_P_C', 'createdTime': '2022-09-23T15:03:59.308Z'}`

and database is:[image: table]

someone can help me with that problem??

I try pass the variable with the query and separated, anyway I get the same error, i don't really understand what was happen with thats Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUES (%%s, %s, %s, %%s, %s)""" % folder_id, None, created_time, parents, "e182c2c8-46ea-472c-adab-c49d60a2998a")
```

There are only three `%s` in that string, but you're passing five values.  That is the error.

`%%s` does not count, because of the extra `%`.

Comment: I don't catch that, i have 5 variables, 4 string and one null, I need how many %s?

Comment: If you have five values, you need five `%s` in the string.